# Angular RXHJ map multiple object properties

Tags: angular, rxjs

My service returns object with events and count properties. Right now I need to do two requests.  First to get events and second to get events count. I'd like to use Observables in component and async pipe in the template. I know how to achieve it subscribing to the service in the component, but I'd like to understand how to map both events and count to an observables with one request. What RxJs operator should I use ?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Event } from '../event.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { EventsService } from '../events.service';
import { first, map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
selector: 'app-events-list',
templateUrl: './events-list.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./events-list.component.css']
})
export class EventsListComponent implements OnInit {

events: Event[];
a$: Observable<Event[]>;
total$: Observable<number>;
pageSize: number = 100;
currentPage: number = 1;

constructor(private eventsService: EventsService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {

this.a$ = this.eventsService.getEvents(this.pageSize, this.currentPage).pipe(
  map(results => results.events)
);

this.total$ = this.eventsService.getEvents(this.pageSize, this.currentPage).pipe(
  map(results => results.count)
);

 }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the response is already an object containing the properties `events` and `count`. So you could initialize a single variable (eg. `events$`) in the controller and use it in the template with `async` pipe.

You could also use `ng-container` tag along with `*ngIf`'s `as` construct to reuse the emissions from the observable. The `ng-container` does not contribute to additional tags and are commented out in the generated DOM.

Try the following

Controller

```js
export class EventsListComponent implements OnInit {
  events: Event[];
  events$: Observable<any>;
  pageSize: number = 100;
  currentPage: number = 1;

  constructor(private eventsService: EventsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.events$ = this.eventsService.getEvents(this.pageSize, this.currentPage);
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(events$ | async) as events">
  Event: {{ events?.events | json }}
  Count: {{ events?.count }}
  
  <sample-comp [sampleInput]="events?.events"></sample-comp>
</ng-container>
```

I've used safe navigation operator `?.` to avoid any `undefined` errors and `json` pipe to render the `events.events` object.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to Michael D's solution you can do this

```
const events$ = this.eventsService.getEvents(this.pageSize, this.currentPage).pipe(
  shareReplay(1),
);

this.a$ = events$.pipe(
  map(results => results.events)
);

this.total$ = events$.pipe(
  map(results => results.count)
);
```

Comment: thank you this one is great solution too, both did the job